# Play FLV videos in ShadowBox

Tags: image, flv, shadowbox, streaming-flv-video

I have been trying to play FLV videos in ShadowBox.

According to the FAQ,

I am using `Shadowbox.init();` on page load.

And then later on

```
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    http://mysite.com/video.flv,
        title:      'video',
        player:     'flv'
    });
```

But to no avail. The video doesnt even stream in the background, I get to see only a black box. However, when I use `player: 'swf'`, the video atleast streams in the background, but doesnt play.

Any help ?

Comment: No answers on SF even after 3 days..? That's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.. !!

With the same code written above..!